# What does "EVERETT COMPATIBILITY" in WinForms source codes mean?

Tags: c#, .net

When investigating the source codes of WinForms release/3.0, I came across so many "FOR EVERETT COMPATIBILITY" comments, for example: [FOR EVERETT COMPATIBILITY in ButtonBaseAdapter](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/6c74471e6d174da251e7c170647b0b0b35149b8e/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/ButtonInternal/ButtonBaseAdapter.cs#L1596C24-L1596C45).
And here: [LayoutOptions.everettButtonCompat](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/6c74471e6d174da251e7c170647b0b0b35149b8e/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/ButtonInternal/ButtonStandardAdapter.cs#L260C20-L260C40)

What does it mean? Does it have anything to do with .NET framework 1.1?

I've searched on google; Everett seems to be a city in Washington, does it mean that EVERETT COMPATIBILITY is some customized codes for some Everett company?

Comment: Given that Microsoft is headquartered in Washington, Everett was presumably an internal project name. It was probably a version of .NET Framework but, at a glance, it's hard to say which one.

Comment: Everett is the code name for Visual Studio .NET 2003.

Comment: Just came to say what PL already said. Found it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_codenames).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everett was the code name for Visual Studio .NET 2003, so I would conclude that it's compatibility with this version of Visual Studio's Windows Forms Designer.

Sources:

1. https://web.archive.org/web/20140414014128/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielfe/archive/2003/09/18/51839.aspx
2. https://www.codemag.com/article/1006081
3. http://www.mypassionfor.net/2005/07/01/code-names/
4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_codenames